# Ambiguous class definition error in C++11 with std::hash

Tags: c++11

I tried to define `int Hash(string key)` in the *hash.cpp* file but it is giving me the error *"hash is ambiguous"*.
I am not sure why. I have distributed the `#includes` in many ways and it still isn't working.

[File: hash.cpp]

```
#include "hash.h"
using namespace std;

int hash::Hash(string key)
{

}
```

[File: hash.h]

```
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

class hash
{
   public:
       int Hash(string key);
};

#endif
```

[FILE: main.cpp]

```
#include<iostream>
#include "hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is why you should not put `using namespace std;` in a header file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that C++11 already comes with `std::hash` ([reference link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/hash/)) which results in the experienced conflict. Either remove the `using namespace std;` and put your class into an own namespace or rename the class to something different.